# Message queue size base on priority

Tags: c#, message-queue, priority-queue

At the moment I use this code to check the size of my MS queue:

```
var msmqManagement = new MSMQManagement();
msmqManagement.Init(q.MachineName, null, q.FormatName);
return (int)msmqManagement.MessageCount >= number;
```

The messages in my queue can have two different priorities (5 or 2) I am looking for fast way to get the total count of message based on the priority. This is what I want:

Total amount of message priority 5 = 1500

Total amount of message priority 2 = 3300

I Googled a lot but I cannot find the right way of doing it. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: One option would be to use two queues, one for each priority.

Comment: Interesting idea but for now not really an option